# Cannot connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to connect to an instance of SQL Server 2008 (Developer Edition) in SQL Server Management Studio but am receiving the following error:

[image: Login Window]

[image: SQL Server Management Studio Error Message]

In SQL Server Configuraton Manager, all services are running and logged in as LocalSystem.

[image: SQL Server Services]

I have set the SQL Native client 10.0 configutarion to enable Shared Memory, TCP/IP, and Named Pipes. I have also set SQL Serer Network Configuration to enable Shared Memory.

[image: SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration(32 bit)]
[image: SQL Natiev Client 10.0 Configuration]
[image: SQL Server Network Configuration]

Comment: what did you input? Try connecting to `localhost` with Windows authentication

Comment: Enable the Named Pipes and TCP/IP in the Protocols section, and then restart the service.  I believe it will work after that.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `Named Pipes` in Protocols of MSSQLSERVER08? Also, is the instance running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default (unnamed) instance uses `MSSQLSERVER` as its service name - so it seems your instance is actually called `MSSQLSERVER08`.

Therefore, you need to use

```
.\MSSQLSERVER08
```

or

```
(local)\MSSQLSERVER08
```

as your server name for connecting...

**Note:**

all these things refer to the **local machine** in the context of connecting to a SQL Server installed on that machine:

- `.`
- `(local)`
- `localhost`
- or your actual **machine name** (whatever it might be)

Comment: For future reference, does ".\" represent local?

Comment: @user1526283: `.` or `(local)` or `localhost` all refer to the local machine. Or you can also specify your machine name as the server name (plus any instance, if present)

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Express use `.\MSSQLSERVER08` as your server name. Try to enable TCP/IP, Shared Memory and Named Pipes from all programs

Also check if the service is started:

[image]

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition

Comment: @user1526283:- Did you check that the service is started?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server and SQL Server Browser are both running.

Answer (score -1):

Restart the SQL Server services. Then try to connect.

OR

If you have Installed SQL server with named instance, browse for for the server name.